# In ms access forms how is it possible to search based on values of two text boxes?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a ms access database with a front end form for users to search specific records and update them accordingly.

My front end form contains two text boxes for search, first gets the checklist number and the 2nd gets the row number on that checklist.

I have one button and by using "Build Event" I have applied the logic as follows:

```
Where condition = [Checklist_Number] Like "*" & [Forms]![Verification Form]![txt_chk_no] & "*" AND [Row_Number] Like "*" & [Forms]![Verification Form]![txt_row] & "*"
```

It works fine in some cases but not fine in all cases.
For example when I type 1 and 1 it takes me to checklist no 1 and row no 1. which is fine.

But when i type 1 and 2, it takes me to checklist no 12 and row no 22.

And i think because 12 and 22 contains 1 and 2,

Now this much i know that something is wrong with the logic, please guide me of some logic where i can get the exact values instead of the similar ones.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited** To show the wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

If your searched fields are indeed numbers then get rid of the Like operator and use = instead. Then you will only get complete matches.

However, I'm surprised that in your sample code without the use of a wildcard

`Like '*" & YourFormRef`
that your code is returning multiple values... ?

Edit : Try this - it assumes both your fields are numbers not text.

```
Where condition = [Checklist_Number] = " & [Forms]![Verification Form]![txt_chk_no] & " AND 
[Row_Number] = " & [Forms]![Verification Form]![txt_row]
```

Comment: thank you but putting = gives an error message as: expression is typed incorrectly or is too complex to be evaluated.

Comment: Having edited your question, I can see you were using the wildcards. So you will need to remove them to use  = instead of the Like operator.

Comment: Not working, can you remove the wildcards in the above statement and write your version of it, that works fine